# Pandas: replace all cells in a subset of columns that contain 0 with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

For the dataframe s6 shown below, I need to:
1. In s6 .iloc[:,4:] replace all cells that contain a 0 with np.nan
2. In s6 .iloc[:,4:] replace all cells that end with a number < 5 with np.nan, where the value in each cell ends with an _Q and then a number.

So for this example dataframe:

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |   col5   |  col6  |  col7   |  col8  | 
 f1       f2      f3       f4       110_q9    111_q4   110_q8    111_q9
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |   col5   |  col6  |  col7   |  col8  | 
 f1       f2      f3       f4         NaN      Nan       NaN     111_q9
```

I've tried many variations on the following, with no success:

```
s6.iloc[:,4:][s6.iloc[:,4:].str.contains('0')] <- np.nan

s6.iloc[:,4:] = s6.iloc[:,4:].replace('*0*', np.nan)

s6.iloc[:,4:] = s6.iloc[:,4:].replace('0',np.nan)

s6.iloc[:,4:] = s6.iloc[:,4:].replace(0,np.nan)

s6 =  [out[out[f].str.split('_Q', expand=True)[1].astype(int) > 5] for f in out.columns if f not in col_list]
```

Solution: 
For the final solution on replacing cells that contain a 0 I altered the answer to also remove cells that did not contain a quality score (uncalled bases) and will post that here as an example of how to apply multiple filters to a subset of a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
for chunk in pd.read_csv(self.input_csv, sep=',', header=0, chunksize=chunksize):
        # create id column
        chunk["id"] = chunk.apply(lambda x : '{}_{}_{}'.format(x[1], x[2], x[3]), axis=1)
        chunk.set_index("id", drop=True, inplace=True)
        chunk.drop(["Features", "fov","x","y"], axis=1, inplace=True) 

        # count and remove uncalled bases
        cols = [x for x in chunk.columns]
        # coerce np array of strings to search
        A = chunk[cols].values.astype(str)
        # mask for uncalled bases on vectorized array
        m1 = np.core.defchararray.find(A, '0') != -1 
        m2 = np.core.defchararray.find(A, '_Q') == -1 
        # apply mask and return filtered columns to df   
        chunk[cols] = np.where(m1|m2, '', chunk[cols]) 

# merge chunks into one dataframe
chunks.append(chunk)
csv= pd.concat(chunks, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by looping through the columns of interest:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = '''\
col1    col2    col3    col4     col5     col6    col7  col8
 f1       f2      f3       f4       110_q9    111_q4   110_q8    111_q9  '''

s6 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

for col in s6.columns[4:]:
    m1 = s6[col].str.contains('0')             # first mask
    m2 = s6[col].str[-3:].str.match('_q[0-4]') # second mask
    s6.loc[m1|m2,col] = np.nan                 # m1 or m2 --> np.nan

print(s6)
```

Returns:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7    col8
0   f1   f2   f3   f4  NaN  NaN  NaN  111_q9
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I was staring at this one for far too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for a vectorised approach. Below is a minimal example. `numpy.core.defchararray.find` returns -1 if the specified character is not found.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['ASFA', 'ASFA0341', '34120'],
                   ['32432', 'SDAF', 'ADS0ADSF'],
                   ['DJKFA', '0SADFSA', 'DAFADF']])

cols = [1, 2]
A = df[cols].values.astype(str)
mask = np.core.defchararray.find(A, '0') != -1
df[cols] = np.where(mask, np.nan, df[cols])

print(df)

       0     1       2
0   ASFA   NaN     NaN
1  32432  SDAF     NaN
2  DJKFA   NaN  DAFADF
```

Comment: I could not get this to work on a column slice s6.iloc[:,4:] and instead kept getting an error. I would to see this modified for a dataframe slice and compare speed with the accepted answer. Thanks so much.